# scala cats, deal with race condition

Tags: multithreading, scala, synchronization, scala-cats

i'm lookning for solution to eleminate race condition in my code.
Basically i have a write and read functions. These functions are called in a stream, of values.
Stream itself is going through parEvalMap(20) from fs2.
I want to be sure there is no race condition between threads.

i know cats effect can context switch on fly, and a can create a single thread threadpool
but isn't there more like built in solution?

Comment: So you want to run 20 things in parallel but in the same thread? What is the race-condition you want to avoid?

Comment: Why does this need to use thread pools? Could it use a semaphore or mutex instead?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez not only read and write, but also a bunch of other things, but this specific part of reading and writing should be done in synchronized way.

Comment: @Daenyth sure, i can use semaphore, but it feels like another threadpool of a single thread should be way easier

Comment: It's much harder, performs worse, and is incredibly non-idiomatic for a CE app

Comment: Do you want to limit *all* concurrent reads and writes? Or is it limited by some key where each key has to have a limit?